# Upgrading TesseractDotNet to newest version

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I am working on an OCR project, where I have to convert images to text. If I had to use English only, then I can make Tesseract work, however as I have to convert also Russian texts, it gets more cumbersome. I am using tesseractdotnet v301_r590 (latest as far as I know) from the following site which works perfecly with language data 3.01:

https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/downloads/list

However when looking at language data for Russian language, I can only see version 3.02 (which is incompatibile with the current version of tesseractdotnet v301_r590). I have tried to download source codes for original tesseract (C++ code) and tried to create a dll out of it; however I cannot even get it started (maybe because I am using VS 2012? I have Visual C++ 2008 as was required by the creators).

My question therefore is - How can I upgrade tesseractdotnet to make it work with 3.02 langauge data, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use Charles Weld's [.Net wrapper for tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) -- it's compatible with version 3.02.